# Having trouble setting up the UART on an AVR Atmega88-PA

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc

I want to set up the UART on a ATmega88-PA. First I was trying to set an interrupt on UDRE register but this was not working, so for the transmission I use normal polling.
Because the code was not working I started again from 0 with a basic program.

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 8UL))) - 1)

char ReceivedByte = '#';

int main (void)
{
    UCSR0A = (1 << U2X0);

    /* Turn on the transmission and reception circuitry. */
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
    /* Use 8-bit character sizes. */
    //UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ00) | (1 << UCSZ01);

    /* BAUD prescale */
    UBRR0 = 12;

    /* Load upper 8-bits of the baud rate value into the high byte of the UBRR register. */
    //UBRR0H = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);
    /* Load lower 8-bits of the baud rate value into the low byte of the UBRR register. */
    //UBRR0L = BAUD_PRESCALE;

    UCSR0B |= (1 << RXCIE0);

    sei();
    DDRB |= 0x04;
    PORTB &= ~0x04;

    for (;;)
    {
        /* Do nothing until data have been received and is ready to be read from UDR. */
        //while ((UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)) == 0) {};
        /* Fetch the received byte value into the variable "ByteReceived". */
        //ReceivedByte = UDR0;

        if(ReceivedByte == '1')
            PORTB |=0x04;
        else
            PORTB &=~0x04;

        /* Do nothing until UDR is ready for more data to be written to it. */
        while ((UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) == 0) {};
        /* Echo back the received byte back to the computer. */
        UDR0 = ReceivedByte;
    }
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    ReceivedByte = UDR0;
}
```

And the code is working but when I open an arduino serial monitor and connect my module to that, I receive my poor # but alog with some garbage.  Not all the time but mostly, the garbage is 1 or 2 byte. Can someone help me?

EDIT: It seams that when I send from my bleutooth data to a Samsung galaxy S3 the data is perfect...I do not have any clue why on serial monitor, and also when sending data using the same bluetooth to laptop I got a lot of garbage along with the data. If this helps you 
answearing my qestion, will be great.

EDIT: sorry forget the last edit, it is send only a char ok, I change the char and also garbage is there. When I send a string is unreadable.

EDIT : As I commneted on the post below of embedded_guy , I solve the problem inserting a _delay_ms(1) after sending each byte. and it is working right now. I believe the statement

```
 while ((UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) == 0) {};
```

is not doing its job. Hope this will help others.

Comment: Do you received the garbage data before or after your '#'?

Comment: As I notice it is after the #, I also send that data over bluetooth to my computer because it is better for reading than the monitor. So i Receive the # then garbage from bluetooth module, and the same is in serial monitor

Comment: Your code looks like you tried to implement the code examples from the data sheet.  then hacked the code.  Many of the commented out code lines are necessary and should not be commented out.

Comment: in the data sheet is stated the requirements about reading the I.O buffer after a byte transmit and the transmit complete is indicated.  I do not see this in your code.

Comment: in the UART Rx interrupt function in your code, the status register needs to be manipulated to reset the UART status flags

Comment: @user3629249 : I am not talking about the receive,and I am not sure about your comment. The status flag is reseted automaticaly on read, as I know, because of using the interrupt. am I right? for the first comment I will look again in specifications.

Comment: Don't see a smoking gun, but I would definitely declare `ReceivedByte` as `volatile`.

Comment: @TravisGriggs I only need to send data, The receive is there only for a full implementation. I also tried to disable that and the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but I really only see a couple of things that could be an issue.

First, all of the examples of setting the BAUD prescale that I could find used two instructions with the high and low registers of `UBRR0`.  If you have already stepped through your code and examined that register to ensure that it is correctly configured, then that is not the issue.  Otherwise, I would recommend setting it like this for the value you have it set to in your code:

```
UBRR0H = 12;
UBRR0L = 0;
```

The other thing I see is that you are never setting `UCSR0C`.  You have it commented out and I would expect it to operate correctly with its default (reset condition) settings, but it is always good to be explicit just in case.

Finally, you may want to take a look at this page on [Simple Serial Communications](http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc).

**EDIT**
Based on your most recent edit, I would take the bluetooth out of the picture.  I would recommend connecting a logic analyzer to the UART transmit pin of your microcontroller and see if the data coming out of the atmega is what you expected.  If that data is good, I would begin looking at *why* the bluetooth is not working as I anticipated.

Comment: I have tried in many ways including that one. Also I had the UCSR0C set , I commnet that because that is the default configuration of the register. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. No the problem is not the bluetooth. Yesturday my laptop bluetooth stoped. I tried to reinstall the driver, and no answear:)). So I use a samsung galaxy like I said. After many time spend I put a _delay_ms(1) after each byte send. And magicaly now everything works. As I believe the statment : while ((UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) == 0) {}; is not working propertly, and the data became corrupt after sending sime bytes

Comment: About the laptop bluetooth, yesturday I restarted the laptop many times, reinstal driver all I could find on internet and nothing. Today I open the laptop and the bluetooth is working..I believe Microsoft has to change some engineers.

Comment: @Manu You can easily verify the output of the microcontroller by using an oscilloscope or a logic analyzer.  Then you will know for certain whether or not your code is functioning as intended.  After that, you can begin troubleshooting bluetooth and the device drivers.  Keep the system simple to begin with.  It looks to me like you were debugging functional code and the problem lies elsewhere... but you can always verify a **part** of your system.

Comment: thats right, is just somedebug. I had the USART working and suddenly wasnot working. So I started from module tests.

Answer (score 0):

try to use F_CPU with at least 2MHz

Comment: Try to be more descriptive. You can provide some sort of explanation of your answer.

Comment: i used to have some problems with UART when i was using
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
there was nothing at all wrong with my code, but the whole thing was fixed when i changed that line to 
#define F_CPU 2000000UL

Answer (score -1):

make your `ReceivedByte` volatile, try it like this:

```
volatile unsigned char ReceivedByte;
```